# rerun ipython cpaste code block

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I ran `%cpaste foo` and saved the code block. I can print the code block by just typing `foo` on the shell.

How do I re-run that piece of code? I tried `exec('foo')` but it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

`%cpaste -r` will rerun the last code block you pasted in there with it.
Do keep in mind that you have to actually execute a function if it's in the block, not just `def` it. If it's an instant action it will return the result.

This actually works, except `foo` is never executed.

```
In [24]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def foo():
:       print("bar")
:--
In [25]: %cpaste -r
Re-executing 'def foo():...' (30 chars) #foo is never called, so there's no result shown
```

This works as well, and foo is executed so you get a result back.

```
In [26]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def foo():
:       print("bar")
:foo()
:--
bar #this is the result of immediate execution 
In [27]: %cpaste -r
Re-executing 'def foo():...' (36 chars)
bar #this is re-runned result
```